# flag provided but not defined: --mount

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm pretty new with Tensorflow Serving, and I followed the basic instruction from: https://tensorflow.google.cn/serving/serving_basic

All previous steps are ok, but when I use:

docker run -p 8500:8500 --mount type=bind,source=/tmp/mnist,target=/models/mnist -e MODEL_NAME=mnist -t tensorflow/serving &

It gave me:
flag provided but not defined: --mount

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: --mount is a new parameter to the docker run command, you should try to update to the latest version of Docker.

Comment: I'm using version=18.06.1    I'm pretty sure it's a new version.